# Como usar a Biblioteca Excel do Laravel

Tags: microsoft-excel, laravel-5

Tenho um `.csv` no qual preciso importar seus dados para a base de dados. Para fazer a importação estou utilizando uma biblioteca do Laravel.

Que é essa daqui: https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

No código estou fazendo assim:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\Excel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ImporterController extends Controller {

# Página de Importação da Lista de Produtos para Base de Dados
public function getIndex(){

    \Excel::load('public/upload/file.csv', function($reader) {

        // Getting all results
        $results = $reader->get();

        // ->all() is a wrapper for ->get() and will work the same
        $results = $reader->all();

        foreach ($results as $key => $var) {
            echo $var."<br>";
        }
    });
}
```

Estou usando um pequeno arquivo `.csv` para fazer o teste e está retornando assim:

> {"100005anel_o":"100006;ANEL O"} {"100005anel_o":"100024;ANEL O"}
>   {"100005anel_o":"100024;ANEL O VITON\n100494;GAXETA"}
>   {"100005anel_o":"100506;VEDADOR"} {"100005anel_o":"100540;VEDADOR"}
>   {"100005anel_o":"100552;RASPADOR"} {"100005anel_o":"100552;RASPADOR"}
>   {"100005anel_o":"100598;RETENTOR"} {"100005anel_o":"100653;RETENTOR"}

Sendo que ele é assim:

[image: Tabela CSV]

Tentei mudar o parâmetros no arquivo de configuração, mas não deu certo também.

```
'csv'        => array(
        /*
       |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
       | Delimiter
       |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
       |
       | The default delimiter which will be used to read out a CSV file
       |
       */

        'delimiter'   => ',',

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Enclosure
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */

        'enclosure'   => '"',

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Line endings
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */

        'line_ending' => "\r\n"
    ),
```

Na verdade na documentação não explica quase nada. Muito escassa de informações.

1 - Como faço para pegar os valores das linhas e colunas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui resolver. No meu caso eu preciso colocar cabeçalho no arquivo **.csv** com o nome das colunas. Nesse caso eram **Código** e **Produto**.

Depois dei mais uma lida na documentação para implementar no código e consegui trazer os registros.

```
        $fileCSV         = Request::file('arquivo');
        $destinationPath = 'upload/';
        $fileName        = $fileCSV->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileExtension   = $fileCSV->getClientOriginalExtension();

        # Verificar Extensão do Arquivo - Apenas .CSV
        if($fileExtension == 'csv'){
            # Faz o Upload Antes da Importação
            $fileCSV->move($destinationPath, $fileName);

            # Excel CSV To Base de Dados
            \Excel::load($destinationPath.'/'.$fileName, function($reader){
                # Lê os Dados
                $result                 = $reader->get();

                # Coloca Cada Linha Dentro de um Array
                $arrData[]              = '';
                foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                    $arrData[] = $value[0];
                }

                # Limpa Array de Linhas Vazias
                $arrData                = array_filter($arrData);

                # Não Repete Códigos Iguais com Descrição Igual no Array
                $arrData                = array_unique($arrData);

                foreach($arrData as $foo => $linha){
                    # Explode em Array
                    $var                = explode(";", $linha);
                    $varCodigo          = $var[0];
                    $varDescricao       = $var[1];

                    $newProd            = new ListaProduto;
                    $newProd->codigo    = $varCodigo;
                    $newProd->produto   = $varDescricao;
                    $newProd->save();
                }
            });

            Session::flash('message-result', 'Produtos Adicionados com Sucesso.');
            return redirect('dashboard/produtos/listar');
        }
```